# Select-Object null error?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to select the "num" and "list" fields from the following json server response:

```
[{"num":"3-4-5-3-2","list":[]},{"num":"1-7-43-2-221","list":[]}]
```

Here is what I have tried with the `Select-Object` command:

```
$content = [{"num":"3-4-5-3-2","list":[]},{"num":"1-7-43-2-221","list":[]}]
$stuff = $content | Select-Object num, list
```

However, when I then try to get information from `$stuff.num` (print the number values, count how many 'num' instances there are, etc), I get an error: `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` - referring to `$stuff.num`

So it appears that calling the `Select-Object` command when there exist multiple instances of the specified object will result in the pointer (`num`) being null. How can I work around this error to get a working list/array/whatever of all `num` instances and their values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using ConvertFrom-Json and then using Select-Object?

```
$Stuff = $ServerResponse | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object num, list
$Stuff.num
```

Comment: What should the `ConvertFrom-Json` parameters be?

Comment: It only has 1 parameter: `-InputObject` which is used when you pipe the data through it in my example. Can't say that I used it as a named parameter but imagine it would still work.